# Gunicorn + multiprocessing.Pool hangs, but only sometimes

Tags: python, flask, python-multiprocessing, gunicorn

I have a flask route where some multiprocessing happens.
This route **always** works fine when running it on the flask development server.
However, when I put Gunicorn in front of my app, the route only works sometimes, the hanging seems random.

In the example, when hanging, it would print:

```
starting... pool
a single process is done, returning None
a single process is done, returning None
```

Then print nothing for a while, then print:

```
[2022-07-01 07:37:23 +0000] [20875] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:20876)
```

And when working correctly it would print:

```
starting... pool
a single process is done, returning None
a single process is done, returning None
Processes are done!
```

Since both the prints are happening just before `None` is returned, I assume that the calls to `process_single` works just fine.
So it looks like something fishy is happening when the `pool` is trying to wrap up.

The dummy code here never seems to cause any issues though :/.

```
def process_single(input1, input2):
    # in my real function, a lot of data processing happens here
    # including some multiprocessing.RawArray and multiprocessing.Lock functionality
    
    # my real function also prints this line just before returning None, it also returns None
    print('a single process is done, returning None')
    return None


input_list = [[1,2],[3,4]]

print('starting... pool')
with Pool(2, maxtasksperchild=1) as pool:
    pool.starmap(process_single, input_list)
    
print('Processes are done!')
```

What could be causing this? What are the alternatives?

EDIT:

Just tried it with mod_wsgi, and interestingly it has the same issue.

Comment: Maybe some uncaught exception happened within your data processing block?